# App has become incompatible with some devices

Tags: android, incompatibility

I noticed recently that my app has become incompatible with some devices 'due to the APK's manifest' (explanation from Play developer console), devices which I know for a fact that were able to run the app. I've looked back at changes of the manifest and the only thing that caught my attention was this:

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="true" />
```

One device that seems to no longer be compatible with the app runs Android 4.4.2 and supports openGL ES 2.0.

Can this be the reason why this is happening? Should I replace the manifest line with the following gradle addition:

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Additional info:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        ...
    }
}
```

and (the only other manifest requirement):

```
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it seems that manifest line influences device compatibility (massively) and the solution is to remove it and add the Gradle declaration.